# get_line(): An alternative implementation of standard C library's getline() function

Tags: c, strings, io

get_line(): An alternative implementation of standard C library's getline() function.

`Syntax: char *get_line(int fd, int *error_num);`

I know that I can declare/define variables anywhere in a function but I don't do that. I use `K & R` style of declaring/defining all variables at the top of the function. So, please don't give review comments on this.

The code has been compiled using the following gcc flags:

-Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wundef -Wunreachable-code -Winit-self -Wparentheses -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-compare -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat-security

The code is below:

---

### get_lines_from_file.c

```
#include "get_lines_from_file.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
 * const char *get_error_string(int error):
 *
 * Function get_error_string() returns the error string corresponding to the
 * value in 'error' argument.
 *
 */
const char *get_error_string(int error)
{

    switch (error) {

        case NO_ERROR:
            return "No error happened.";
        case INVALID_FD:
            return "Invalid fd. fd value is less than 0.";
        case NO_MEMORY:
            return "No memory available.";
        case NO_MORE_DATA:
            return "The file doesn't have any more data.";
        default:
            return "Invalid error number given.";

    }

} // end of print_error_string

/*
 * char *get_line(int fd, int *error_num):
 * 
 * Function get_line() returns a line from the file represented by fd.
 *
 * This function supports regular files only (and not pipes, sockets, etc).
 *
 * If fd is less than 0 then NULL is returned and if error_num is not NULL, then
 * *error_num is assigned the appropriate error value (INVALID_FD in this case).
 *
 * In case of any error, if error_num is not NULL then *error_num is assigned
 * the appropriate error value.
 *
 * The high level algorithm of this function is:
 *
 *      The function get_line() reads some bytes in a buffer from the file and
 *      tries to find newline in the buffer. If a newline is not found then it
 *      reads more bytes from the file in the buffer. When a newline is found in
 *      the buffer, then the newline is replaced with null byte and the buffer
 *      is reallocated to correct size. Then the file offset for reading is set
 *      to the start of the next line. And then the buffer is returned to the user.
 *
 * Please note that the returned line/buffer doesn't contain any newlines.
 *
 * The line/buffer returned by this function is allocated using realloc(), so it is
 * user's responsibility to free the line (free memory).
 *
 */
char *get_line(int fd, int *error_num)
{

#define NEW_LINE '\n'
#define BUF_SIZE_INCREMENT 256 // normally lines are not greater than 256 bytes.

    char *buf = NULL;
    char *buf_addr_holder = NULL;
    long index_to_load_data = 0;
    long curr_buf_size = 0;
    long num_chars_read = 0;
    ssize_t ret_val = -1;
    int end_of_file_reached_or_error = 0;
    int new_line_found = 0;
    long i = 0;

    if (error_num)
        *error_num = NO_ERROR;

    if (fd < 0) {
        if (error_num)
            *error_num = INVALID_FD;
        return NULL;
    }

    while (1) {

#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s: curr_buf_size before realloc = %ld.\n", __FILE__, curr_buf_size);
#endif

        buf_addr_holder = realloc(buf, (size_t)(curr_buf_size + BUF_SIZE_INCREMENT));
        if(!buf_addr_holder) {
            free(buf);
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s:%d: buffer has been freed.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
#endif
            if (error_num)
                *error_num = NO_MEMORY;
            return NULL;
        }
        curr_buf_size = curr_buf_size + BUF_SIZE_INCREMENT;
        buf = buf_addr_holder;
        index_to_load_data = num_chars_read;

#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s: curr_buf_size after realloc = %ld.\n", __FILE__, curr_buf_size);
#endif

        // read data from file
        while (1) {

            ret_val = read(fd, buf + index_to_load_data, (size_t)(curr_buf_size - num_chars_read));

            if (ret_val <= 0) {
                if (num_chars_read == 0) {
                    if (error_num)
                        *error_num = NO_MORE_DATA;
                    if (buf) {
                        free(buf);
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s:%d: buffer has been freed.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
#endif
                    }
                    return NULL;
                } else {
                    end_of_file_reached_or_error = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            num_chars_read = num_chars_read + ret_val;

            if (num_chars_read == curr_buf_size)
                break;

        } // end of inner while (1)

        if (num_chars_read > curr_buf_size) {
            printf("%s: Some bug in program. num_chars_read (%ld) is greater than"
                   " curr_buf_size (%ld). Exiting..\n", __FILE__, num_chars_read, curr_buf_size);
            exit(1);
        }

#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        if (num_chars_read < curr_buf_size) {
            printf("%s: num_chars_read (%ld) is less than curr_buf_size (%ld).\n",
                   __FILE__, num_chars_read, curr_buf_size);
        } else if (num_chars_read == curr_buf_size) {
            printf("%s: num_chars_read (%ld) is equal to curr_buf_size (%ld).\n",
                   __FILE__, num_chars_read, curr_buf_size);
        }
#endif

        new_line_found = 0;

        for (i = index_to_load_data; i < num_chars_read; i++) {
            if (buf[i] == NEW_LINE) {
                buf[i] = 0;
                new_line_found = 1;
                break;
            }
        } // end of for loop

        if (new_line_found) {

            // realloc and seek
            buf_addr_holder = realloc(buf, (size_t)(i + 1));
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s: buffer reallocated from %ld bytes to %ld bytes.\n", __FILE__, curr_buf_size, i + 1);
#endif
            if(!buf_addr_holder) { // strange, this should not happen
                free(buf);
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s:%d: buffer has been freed.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
#endif
                if (error_num)
                    *error_num = NO_MEMORY;
                return NULL;
            }
            lseek(fd, (i + 1) - num_chars_read, SEEK_CUR);
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
            printf("%s: Seeking %ld bytes from current read offset.\n", __FILE__, (i + 1) - num_chars_read);
#endif
            return buf_addr_holder;

        } else { // new line not found

            // new line not found and end of file has been reached.
            // so, allocate one extra byte for terminating null byte and return.
            if (end_of_file_reached_or_error) {
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s: Newline not found in buffer but end of file reached. curr_buf_size"
               " = %ld, num_chars_read = %ld.\n", __FILE__, curr_buf_size, num_chars_read);

        if (num_chars_read == curr_buf_size) {
            printf("%s: -----THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN-----. NEWLINE NOT FOUND IN BUFFER BUT"
                   " END OF FILE REACHED AND CURR_BUF_SIZE AND NUM_CHARS_READ ARE EQUAL"
                   " (%ld).\n", __FILE__, curr_buf_size);
        }
#endif
                buf_addr_holder = realloc(buf, (size_t)(num_chars_read + 1));
                if(!buf_addr_holder) {
                    free(buf);
#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s:%d: buffer has been freed.\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
#endif
                    if (error_num)
                        *error_num = NO_MEMORY;
                    return NULL;
                }
                buf_addr_holder[num_chars_read] = 0;
                return buf_addr_holder;
            }

        } // end of if - else (new_line_found)

#ifdef DEBUG_ON
        printf("%s: Newline not found in buffer, reading more data. curr_buf_size"
               " = %ld, num_chars_read = %ld.\n", __FILE__, curr_buf_size, num_chars_read);
#endif

    } // end of outer while (1)

} // end of get_line
```

---

### get_lines_from_file.h

```
#ifndef GET_LINES_FROM_FILE_H
#define GET_LINES_FROM_FILE_H

enum {
    NO_ERROR = 0, // no error happened.
    INVALID_FD = -1, // fd is less than 0.
    NO_MEMORY = -2, // memory not available.
    NO_MORE_DATA = -3, // file has no bytes/characters.
};

/*
 * char *get_line(int fd, int *error_num):
 * 
 * Function get_line() returns a line from the file represented by fd.
 * 
 * This function supports regular files only (and not pipes, sockets, etc).
 *
 * If fd is less than 0 then NULL is returned and if error_num is not NULL, then
 * *error_num is assigned the appropriate error value (INVALID_FD in this case).
 *
 * In case of any error, if error_num is not NULL then *error_num is assigned
 * the appropriate error value.
 *
 * The high level algorithm of this function is:
 *
 *      The function get_line() reads some bytes in a buffer from the file and
 *      tries to find newline in the buffer. If a newline is not found then it
 *      reads more bytes from the file in the buffer. When a newline is found in
 *      the buffer, then the newline is replaced with null byte and the buffer
 *      is reallocated to correct size. Then the file offset for reading is set
 *      to the start of the next line. And then the buffer is returned to the user.
 *
 * Please note that the returned line/buffer doesn't contain any newlines.
 *
 * The line/buffer returned by this function is allocated using realloc(), so it is
 * user's responsibility to free the line (free memory).
 *
 */
char *get_line(int fd, int *error_num);

/*
 * const char *get_error_string(int error):
 *
 * Function get_error_string() returns the error string corresponding to the
 * value in 'error' argument.
 *
 */
const char *get_error_string(int error);

#endif
```

---

### test_get_lines_from_file.c

```
#include "get_lines_from_file.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static void print_usage_and_exit(void)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("Usage: test_get_lines_from_file file_name\n");
    printf("\n");
    exit(1);

} // print_usage_and_exit

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    int fd = -1;
    char *line = NULL;
    int error_num = 0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("\nOnly two arguments are required. Program name and file name.\n");
        print_usage_and_exit();
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("\n%s: File \"%s\" could not be opened. Exiting..\n", __FILE__, argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((line = get_line(fd, &error_num)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        free(line);
    }

    if ((error_num != NO_ERROR) && (error_num != NO_MORE_DATA)) {
        printf("%s\n", get_error_string(error_num));
    }

    close(fd);

} // end of main
```

Comment: If you're really using K&R style, you should also be using old-style function definitions instead of prototypes - why so inconsistent?

Comment: What I have found out is that people here review programming styles rather than reviewing for bugs, wrong logic, major performance improvements, etc.

Comment: I have also not seen anyone giving positive reviews like `I have reviewed your code and it all looks good`. In this case, people skip giving reviews. People here are only interested in giving negative code reviews.

Comment: Well done on encouraging people to review your code, mate!

Comment: The code review that happens in a software company is more about bugs, wrong logic, performance improvements, optimizations, etc. rather than programming style. Out here, on codereview.stackexchange.com, it is the opposite - almost all focus is on programming style rather than bugs, wrong logic, etc.

Comment: @Amit, you clearly work in a different software company than I do.  My development team do care about correctness (that's normally proven by the unit tests), but they also care that the code is _maintainable_.  Good style helps a team to keep code correct when it has to be updated due to new requirements.

Comment: I have worked for Cisco Systems and Juniper Networks.

Comment: `normally lines are not greater than 256 bytes.` -- [citation needed]

Answer (score 4):

You already know you need to move your variables to smaller scope where possible, so no need to say any more about that.  (K&R C never required variables to all be declared at *function* scope.)

The `get_line` interface seems to prevent writing a pure filter that preserves input that's not properly terminated with newline.  You may or may not consider that a problem.

`get_error_string` seems like a name that's prone to collision - you probably want to make that more specific.  Or just use the usual `errno` values such as `EBADF` and `ENOMEM` (which gets you translated error messages without extra work, and stops you having to fold down many different kinds of error into a few less informative ones).

I don't see any good reason for `NEW_LINE` and `BUF_SIZE_INCREMENT` to be macros (rather than ordinary C constant objects).

We can simplify some expressions and make them easier to read.  In particular,

```
    curr_buf_size = curr_buf_size + BUF_SIZE_INCREMENT;
        num_chars_read = num_chars_read + ret_val;
```

It's much kinder on your readers to use addition assignment:

```
    curr_buf_size += BUF_SIZE_INCREMENT;
        num_chars_read += ret_val;
```

If we get an error on our first read (e.g. `fd` isn't a readable file descriptor) then we report "no more data" instead of a proper error.

`if (buf) free(buf);` has a pointless condition.  `free(buf);` is a much simpler replacement (since `free()` is specified to do nothing when passed a null pointer).

It's very hard to read the `DEBUG_ON` sections that are outdented with respect to their enclosing scopes.  Code within preprocessor conditionals normally retains its indentation level.

Tests of program logic should normally not be included when `NDEBUG` is defined, so that they work like `assert()`.  And our error needs to go to the correct output stream:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
        if (num_chars_read > curr_buf_size) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "%s:%d: Some bug in program. num_chars_read (%ld) is greater than"
                    " curr_buf_size (%ld). Exiting..\n",
                    __FILE__, __LINE__,
                    num_chars_read, curr_buf_size);
            exit(1);
        }
#endif
```

We really don't want a library function to `exit()` the whole program unilaterally, even if the library is faulty.

This loop is crazy:

> ```
>     for (i = index_to_load_data; i < num_chars_read; i++) {
>         if (buf[i] == NEW_LINE) {
>             buf[i] = 0;
>             new_line_found = 1;
>             break;
>         }
>     } // end of for loop
> ```

There's really no reason to write our own `memchr()` implementation every time.

Variable `i` needs to be `size_t`, and to have a better name given the large scope.  Single-letter names should only be used for variables with small scope.

When we find a newline, we attempt to unread it using `lseek()` but never test whether it was successful (as it won't be when reading a pipe, for example).  This will result in data loss.  It might be a good idea to test whether `fd` is seekable right at the start of the function, before we read anything from it.

The test program prints its error messages to `stdout` - use `stderr` instead.  Consider using `perror()` (or `fprintf()` with `strerror(errno)`) to get more informative diagnostics when the file can't be opened.

As usual, it would be better if we could arrange some self-checking tests rather than having to rely on the tester's inspection of results.

Comment: Toby, thanks for the review.

Comment: @Amit We have a button for that.

Comment: Toby, you didn't give the `positive review comment` that you couldn't find any bugs in the program while reviewing it.

Comment: The only bug that I spotted was the data loss when the input stream isn't seekable.

Comment: That's not a bug. This program is designed to handle files only, not pipes, etc.

Comment: Toby, the flexibility of declaring/defining variables when needed came with C99 in 1999. `K & R` was much before that. So, `K & R` `did require that all the variables be declared/defined at the top of the function`.

Comment: Toby, another point is that if declaring/defining variables when needed is superior coding style then why didn't `K & R` do it from the beginning. They were very intelligent people and they could have done it easily. But they didn't do it. The only explanation for this would be that they also didn't think that declaring/defining variables when needed is superior style.

Comment: You can say to users "don't do that" - but inevitably they will.  If you want them only to use regular files and not sockets or character devices, robust code will verify that and emit a meaningful diagnostic.  Personally, I would find that a quite limiting restriction, but even an error message is certainly better than data corruption.

Comment: And no, C has _always_ allowed variables to have smaller scope than an entire function, even back when their declarations had to be at the start of their containing block.  (I'm not sure that you're in a position to claim what was "easy" for Brain and Dennis, nor to know which features were highest priority for them; for example function prototypes weren't in pre-Standard C, but we all agree they are a good thing.)

Comment: What about this then: `$ gcc -std=c89 -pedantic example.c
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:3:46: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
`. The code is `int main(void) { int c = 0; printf("234\n"); int d = 0; }`.

Comment: `gcc -x c -std=c89 -pedantic - <<<'int main(void) { int i=1; --i; { int j=i; return j; } }'` Are you being deliberately obtuse, or do you really not understand?  Either way, I don't have time for this today.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote this: `And no, C has always allowed variables to have smaller scope than an entire function`. What does this mean? I thought that you are trying to say that C always allowed declare/define variables when needed. But if you were not saying that then what was the intention of this statement. I don't think we were discussing about scope of variables. We were discussing about declaring/defining variables at the top of the function vs declaring/defining variables when needed.

Comment: I don't know how to say it more clearly.  Variables do not need to all be defined at the beginning of a _function_.  That's what I wrote and that's what I meant.

Comment: @Amit `That's not a bug. This program is designed to handle files only, not pipes, etc.` in *nix terminology a pipe is a (kind of) file.

Comment: Richard, I meant regular files. Pipe is not a regular file.

Comment: There was a bug in the test program but no one caught it. The fd (file) was not closed in the test program. However, I have fixed it now.

Comment: Arguable whether that was actually a bug, since exiting the process releases all open file descriptors anyway.  I agree it's good style do explicitly close it, at least in debug builds (which you might want to test under Valgrind).

Comment: Toby, I don't think that it is correct logic that fds will be closed anyways when the program exits. All programs should be correct (at least, that's my preference) - like - if you open a file then close it before exiting, if you allocate memory then free it before exiting, etc.

Comment: You might not think that's correct, but [POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01) _Process termination caused by any reason shall have the following consequences: … **All of the file descriptors, directory streams, conversion descriptors, and message catalog descriptors open in the calling process shall be closed.**_  Seems pretty unarguable to me.

Comment: Toby, I didn't say that it is not correct. I said that this should not be used as an excuse to not close fds explicitly.

Comment: You specifically said, "_I don't think that it is correct logic that fds will be closed anyways when the program exits_."

Comment: Toby, I forgot to add the rest in that line. My complete line was this: I don't think that it is correct logic that since fds will be closed anyways (when the program exits) so its ok if they are not closed explicitly.

Comment: @TobySpeight , there is a bug in the program but you didn't notice that. In the inner while loop (where data is being read), I am giving the address to store data as `buf + index_to_load_data`, `but index_to_load_data is not updated in the loop`. So, if read() ends up being called multiple times, then it will read new data at the same address every time, thus overwriting old data which we don't want. `In code review, priority should be given to finding bugs and then to coding style.`